# Thumbnail Gallery - How to keep the large center image from distorting when clicking on the thumbnail images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, gallery

This is the code I am using to make a thumbnail gallery. It works pretty well, but the large images keep distorting when I click on the thumbnails. I dont know how to fix this. This is not completely my own code, so I don't understand it fully - please note that I am very new to this and am only jumping into an advanced problem (at least to me) out of necessity. Any help would truly be appreciated!! Thanks in advance.

```
<!-- image code --><script type="text/javascript">
function mb1_getObjectByID(id,o){
 var c,el,els,f,m,n; if(!o)o=document; if(o.getElementById) el=o.getElementById(id);
 else if(o.layers) c=o.layers; else if(o.all) el=o.all[id]; if(el) return el;
 if(o.id==id || o.name==id) return o; if(o.childNodes) c=o.childNodes; if(c)
 for(n=0; n<c.length; n++) { el=FP_getObjectByID(id,c[n]); if(el) return el; }
 f=o.forms; if(f) for(n=0; n<f.length; n++) { els=f[n].elements;
 for(m=0; m<els.length; m++){ el=FP_getObjectByID(id,els[n]); if(el) return el; } }
 return null;
}
function mb1_swapImg(i){
    mb1Obj=mb1_getObjectByID('mb1Img'+i);
    var imgAry = String(mb1Obj.value).split('|');
    mb1BigImg=mb1_getObjectByID('bigImg');
    mb1BigImg.src = imgAry[0];
    mb1BigImg.width = imgAry[1];
    mb1BigImg.height = imgAry[2];
    return true;
}
</script>
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top">
        <div style="padding:4px;"><img alt="" border="0" height="64" id="thmb0" name="thmb0" onclick="mb1_swapImg('0')" src="[IMAGE1_URL]" style="cursor:pointer" width="43" /></div>
        <input id="mb1Img0" name="mb1Img0" type="hidden" value="[IMAGE1_URL]|380|570" />
        <div style="padding:4px;"><img alt="" border="0" height="64" id="thmb1" name="thmb1" onclick="mb1_swapImg('1')" src="[IMAGE2_URL]" style="cursor:pointer" width="43" /></div>
        <input id="mb1Img1" name="mb1Img1" type="hidden" value="[IMAGE2_URL]|380|570" />
        <div style="padding:4px;"><img alt="" border="0" height="64" id="thmb2" name="thmb2" onclick="mb1_swapImg('2')" src="[IMAGE3_URL]" style="cursor:pointer" width="43" /></div>
        <input id="mb1Img2" name="mb1Img2" type="hidden" value="[IMAGE3_URL]|380|570" />
        <div style="padding:4px;"><img alt="" border="0" height="64" id="thmb3" name="thmb3" onclick="mb1_swapImg('3')" src="[IMAGE4_URL]" style="cursor:pointer" width="43" /></div>
        <input id="mb1Img3" name="mb1Img3" type="hidden" value="[IMAGE4_URL]|380|570" />
        <div style="padding:4px;"><img alt="" border="0" height="64" id="thmb4" name="thmb4" onclick="mb1_swapImg('4')" src="[IMAGE5_URL]" style="cursor:pointer" width="43" /></div>
        <input id="mb1Img4" name="mb1Img4" type="hidden" value="[IMAGE5_URL]|380|570" />
        <div style="padding:4px;"><img alt="" border="0" height="64" id="thmb5" name="thmb5" onclick="mb1_swapImg('5')" src="[IMAGE6_URL]" style="cursor:pointer" width="43" /></div>
        <input id="mb1Img5" name="mb1Img5" type="hidden" value="[IMAGE6_URL]|380|570" />
        <div style="padding:4px;"><img alt="" border="0" height="64" id="thmb6" name="thmb6" onclick="mb1_swapImg('6')" src="[IMAGE7_URL]" style="cursor:pointer" width="43" /></div>
        <input id="mb1Img6" name="mb1Img6" type="hidden" value="[IMAGE7_URL]|380|570" /></td>
        <td align="center" valign="top"><img alt="" border="0" height="570" id="bigImg" name="bigImg" src="[IMAGE1_URL]" width="380" /></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

http://s952.photobucket.com/user/mlahrichi22/library/

Comment: Can you post an image of how the larger images are displaying and how they should display?

Comment: Thank you so much for responding. I appreciate it! I just uploaded a photobucket library with two images. One of the images (originally landscape) was distorted when I clicked on it and the other (originally portrait) was not. I believe that this is because the code just fits an image to be 380 x 571.  Thank you :)